# How to get a valid SSL Cert for Private Route 53 hosted zone on a VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate, vpn, openvpn

I have created a VPN (via an Client VPN Enpoint), which has access to a VPC in AWS - from which I can resolve a private domain from a Private Route 53 hosted zone. (dashboard.internal)

This is all working brilliantly, I can connect to the VPN and access the intranet app via the custom domain name - but now I am looking to add HTTPS to the internal ALB so it plays nice in the browser.

What is the correct procedure to get the certificate valid and trusted by the browser? I created a self signed one, to get the infra working - but the browser is obviously not liking that.

Is it possible to give the `.ovpn` file I use to connect to the VPN info about this cert?
(Although as this is a prototype the Client VPN bit will probably be chucked in favor of Direct Connenct)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a private certificate using ACM. ACM supports private certificates.

1. Add a certificate authority (CA) [ACM -> Private CA's]
2. Request a Private Certificate [ACM -> Request Certificate -> Private Certificate]

Now you can use this certificate with all AWS Services.

Since, you are already using an ALB you can directly attach the private certificate to ALB itself.

Comment: Hi @AtulSharma, thanks! I've create the Private CA, created a cert and attached. However the browser is still not trusting the AWS generated cert. Is there something else I would need to do to make this work?

Comment: @otvyzxdzrvogyrfqxr did you end up figuring out what was causing your browser not to trust the certificate?

Comment: This is an expensive option just FYI.